# How can I put the hover event in each list with useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

HEllo I want to do the hover event on each list box that made by json files.
Each box has image what I want to do is, when the mouse on the image. It should be disappear.
but when I put the useState hook it applied every box..
How I put the event each of li box.

```
partnersIcons.json 
[
  {
    "image":"../img/1_a.png"
  },
  {
    "image":"../img/1_b.png"
  },
  {
    "image":"../img/1_c.png"
  }
]
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import styled from "styled-components";
import partnerIcons from './json/partnersIcon.json';

const Icorn = styled.img`
padding:4px;
vertical-align:middle;
display:block;

&.hidden{
  display:none;
}
`
const Ul = styled.ul`
width:75%;
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:190px 190px 190px 190px 190px; 
margin: 0 auto;
@media ${({ theme }) => theme.device.tablet} {
 display:none;
  
}
`

const Wrap =()=>{
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);  
  const pIcornWrap = partnerIcons.map((item, index)=>{
    return(
      <Li key={index}>
        <Icorn src ={item.image} onMouseOver={()=>{setVisible(!visible);}} onMouseDown={()=>{setVisible(!visible);}} className={visible? 'show':'hidden'}></Icorn>
      </Li>
    )
  });
  return(
    <div>
      
      <Ul>
        {pIcornWrap}
      </Ul>
      <MobileView><PartnersPage/></MobileView>
    </div>
  )
  
}
```

Comment: try passing key to setVisible instead of true and match key with visible to show

Answer (score 0):

Just use css

```
li.className img:hover {
    display:none;
}
```